# Quirky if statement

Tags: php, image-processing, if-statement

It seems that my if statement, which I've posted below is not functioning properly. I honestly don't see any problem so I'm stumped. If `$filetype` = PNG the if statement stops at the first statement and runs that, even though it's only to run if `$filtype` = JPG

**Here is my code:**

```
if ($filetype = "JPG")
{
$img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
}
elseif ($filetype = "GIF")
{
$img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src);  
}
elseif ($filetype = "PNG")
{
$img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);  
}
```

What am I not seeing?

If I change the code so that it reads...

```
if ($filetype = "PNG")
{
$img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);
}
elseif ($filetype = "GIF")
{
$img_r = imagecreatefromgif($src);  
}
elseif ($filetype = "PNG")
{
$img_r = imagecreatefrompng($src);  
}
```

...and `$filetype = "PNG"` everything works just fine.

Comment: You're confusing the equality operator `==` with the assignment operator `=`.

Comment: @andrewsi Simple answers are answers too. Why put it in a comment? :)

Comment: That was it, thank you! It's always the simple things. :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ($filetype = "JPG")
```

This is an assignment, not a comparison.

```
if ($filetype == "JPG")
```

will do what you want it to do.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's always something simple that I look over. :-)

Comment: @JeffPeak **MAN!** `Assignment =` vs. `comparison ==`, two VERY different bowls of fish. It's not a simple error... if you deleted some file in that `if` :)

Comment: Luckily I wasn't deleting or changing anything important. I just forgot the extra `=` sign because sometimes my brain turns off. NEED MORE COFFEE!! I haven't ever made this mistake before and I feel silly now for posting it here.

Comment: @JeffPeak - have you thought about using Yoda Conditions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_Conditions

Comment: @andrewsi Clever for suggesting this, you are.

Comment: In addition to adopting Yoda notation, consider an IDE that can indicate that you may have made a mistake. I use NetBeans IDE, and when performing an assignment as an expression to an `if` statement, it warns you that "*this may not be something you want to do*".